# Avoid VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA when changing enviorements

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a SSIS Package that imports an excel file and dumps the data in an SQL Server 2012 table. The package runs monthly and both the excel file name and the sheet name change monthly.

It runs smoothly in the development environment. My problem is that when I deploy it to the production environment I always get the VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error.

I've tried:

- Setting DelayValidation to "True".
- Hardcoding the sheet name, instead of getting it at runtime.
- Opening the task and refresh the columns, using the exact same file I'll be importing in the production enviorement, before deploying.

None of these worked. The only thing that changes (besides the environment itself) is the file path because it must be different between the development and production environment. The sheet name is the same and the file metadata is the same (because the file content is also the same).

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you changing the path to your file between DEV and PROD? If you're opening the package and changing the data source, I can see where it would need to re-validate things.

Comment: It is a variable based on an expression (to add the month to the filename). The base comes from a package configuration inside an SQL table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the path changes from the Dev server to Prod server, the underlying XML needs to be updated as well. Hence you get the error.

To avoid it, try keeping the paths same. If that is not possible, create a folder structure to match up the Production and make your packages read/write from these mock up locations. Once you deploy these new packages, you should not see any VS_NEEDS..... message.